# Ricoh SP 4510SF freezes with SC899 or SC900 error code at random

Tags: networking, network-printer, cups

The **Ricoh** printer **SP 4510SF** crashes at random with error code `SC899` or `SC900` which means application error. Then it is needed to reboot the printer.

We have several of those printers and only one at a specific **IP** address has this issue. Exchange the printer at this **IP** address does not solve the issue. Any printer at the specific **IP** becomes faulty and the faulty works smoothly at another address.

Reset, reinstall or update the firmware does not solve the issue.

This leads to believe that either:

1. There must be a job that crashes the printer.
2. There must be something related to this **IP** address.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging with **Wireshark** we found out that the billing system was performing the following **HTTP Request** only at this printer:

- `REQUEST1 -> /web/entry/en/websys/webprinter/jobHistory.cgi`

For the others the **HTTP Request** was a bit different:

- `REQUEST2 -> /web/entry/en/websys/jobList/jobListGetHistory.cgi`

By blocking **REQUEST1** the issue was gone. On doing more tests we were not able to reproduce this issue by flooding one printer with several **REQUEST1**. We believe that the printer also needs to be processing jobs for this to work.